# ASP.NET Core 2.1, External login without local Identity

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core

I already setup the MVC external login with my own OAuth2 provider. It seems the default "ASP.NET Identity" will still create the user locally (Using the default Entity Framework DB).

[image]

Is it possible to avoid this and completely leave the authentication to the external party? Like the Windows Authentication or JWT based WebAPI.

I tried to follow [Use cookie authentication without ASP.NET Core Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x) but it goes nowhere.

Comment: Just start w/o Identity template and use  `services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options => { ... })` followed by `app.UseAuthentication()` in the `Configure` method

Comment: You need ASP.NET Core Identity only if you want to have locally managed users (thats also what the description says, when you choose "Individual Authentication" on an MVC project)  and use the external providers for authenticating these users and then connect that authentication with their accounts

Comment: @Tseng This seems to be working if I provide the token, but for a MVC application I need to use cookies instead.

Comment: Yes, for MVC you need Cookies. The comment was about WebApi since you explicitly mentioned JWT based WebApi and to MVC you can't pass the bearer token on each request. For MVC you'd use the external OAuth/OpenID proviers, i.e. `.AddXxx` (`.AddGoogle`, `.AddFacebook`, `AddOpenIdConnect` (for general purpose OIDC authentication etc.)